# I am not getting whats wrong with my ajax code

Tags: ajax

Its displaying error missing : after property id

```
$.ajax({
url:"save.php",
data:"param="+escape(name),
dataType:"html",
cache:"false",
success(result){
$(".right").html(result);
}
});
```

Comment: Could you share us some more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`success` is a property you can assign your callback function to, like:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"save.php",
    data:"param="+escape(name),
    dataType:"html",
    cache:"false",
    success: function(result){
        $(".right").html(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax for the success() callback:
    success: function() { ... }